# What is the most effective way for me to request to have my probation period ended early?

Tags: professionalism, probation

Here is my situation, I left my Job 3 months ago for a different job, long story short I hated the new job and returned to my old position within the month.

Now I am looking to buy a house, and I have found a house I fell in love with. Mortgage is approved on the condition that my probation is cut short.

My probation is 6 months, I have been back in the position for 2 months, I held the position previously for 2 and a half years.

How do I approach my employer about ending my probation period early?

Comment: Usually if you are on probation, mortgages are hard to come by. Due to the circumstance of me being in a Job I only just left after a substantial amount of time In the role, the bank have agreed - on the condition my probation is over. Im a first time buyer so honestly i am no expert! All I know is i need a letter saying the probation is over.

Comment: **Which country are you in?** What do a) that country's employment laws b) your contract, say about probation?

Comment: Why is there any probation period at all if you previously held the same position for 2.5 years? You've already proven capable of doing the job to the expected standard. Did they only take you back under some conditions? The employer can choose to waive that at any time, really. Talk to your supervisor.

Answer (score 108):

You're in a reasonable position to ask, since the point of a probation period is to ascertain whether you are a good fit for the job and you can already demonstrate that.

But it is entirely up to the employer as to whether they agree to permit it. You have signed a contract with a 6 month probation period, and the only way to change that is by mutual consent.

Comment: Depending on local law the probation period may not be legal...

Answer (score 12):

What we think doesn't matter here, what your employer thinks is crucial.

Talk to your employer, objectively explain your situation, ask nicely while ensuring them that you really want to stay this time. That said, don't expect too much of a concession if you left on bad terms...

Answer (score 0):

I guess it comes down to your employer. Explain your situation. I'm sure they'll be able to help you.

I was able to cut my probation down before signing my contract to my current job. I was suddenly made redundant beforehand therefore my house offer had fell through.

My current employer was really understanding of the circumstance. Not only did he reduce the probation period but also arranged for a letter to be written to the mortgage lender, stating I was in a full-time position and also my probation period had been completed.

Good luck!

Comment: I dont understand, If you were redundant, why they give you a permanent position?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza: "Before signing my contract" means Ollie is talking about the previous employer.